# Load Same Code Twice In Separate Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a resource database that has a scrolling container on the side. Essentially, when you click a thumbnail within the container, it will load the contents of a div which will fade in and display content for that category. Each div tag looks something like this:

```
<div>
<h2>Category1</h2>
<p><a style="float:right" class="a_demo_four" href="/Resources/file1.pdf" target="_blank">
                        Download
</a>File Desc</p> 
<hr/> 
</div>
```

And will load as such: [image]

Essentially, I want to be able to display the same exact content when I open another category on this page. I have several different categories, and want to be able to pull the code from say Category1, Category2, and so on and so forth so I can display all of them in a "View All" tab. I've attempted to use jQuery's load function as seen below:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script> 
$(function() {
$("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 
}); 
</script> 
</head>

<body>
 <div id="includedContent"></div>
 <h1>This is why I rule</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

to load the content from the original div into the view all category, but nothing shows up. Unfortunately, I have very limited knowledge with Javascript/jQuery so I'm having difficulty being able to use the same content in a different div without just copying and pasting the code over. This would also pose problems in the future when I am adding files and have to edit the code twice if I did so.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your content in a variable like this:

```
var content = '';
$(document).ready(function(){
  //load first in a div
  $('#includedContent').load('b.html', function(result){
    content = result;
    //from here on, you know you have b.html data in the variable content
    //and you can use it elsewhere like this
    $('#anotherDivId').html(content);
  });
});
```

Comment: if $("#includedContent").load("b.html"); gives no resuls, you may be working locally or the route to the file is bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you call your code within document ready function will work.
Try,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 

});
```

However you will probably need to keep it somewhere as visualex suggested in order to add the content in multiple places as you require.

This is a working jsfiddle,
http://jsfiddle.net/c5SAH/show/

it loads content from 
http://jsfiddle.net/gfgE8/show/